# Confusion about difference between application container and application server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, jboss

I know that there is another topic that is similar but my question is
"what is the difference between application server and application container"
Not
"What is the difference between application server and servlet container"

I know that application container is used interchangeable with servlet container. But is it really correct? I'm not sure because we can have many types of container for example EJB container or JMS container. So EJB container is also the same as application container? I'm I right if I say that application container is general name for different containers like servlet container, ejb container, hibernate container and so on?

I don't understand what container means(what is the definition?) and how it is connected with application server.

All this staff with naming convention is not clear for me(application container/web container/...). Please help me to understand it and put it in a clear way.

Comment: Application container word is misused. Have a look at https://blog.risingstack.com/operating-system-containers-vs-application-containers/

Comment: So, Tomcat is not application container?

Comment: Tomcat is web container only. JBoss and other EJB service providers are application servers.